# C++ User inputs a char, the variable stays 0

Tags: c++, input, char, cin

I'm trying to create a tic-tac-toe game where the user inputs a number (corresponding to the position he wants place his X or O), but the variable (Move) which receives the number stays at 0 no matter what the input is. Can you help me figure out what to fix so the variable actually receives what the user inputs? Here is the code for the function which receives the move:

```
int FDeclarations::GetMove(){
int Move;
std::cin >> Move;
return Move;}
```

Here is the code for the function which goes through the switch statement (none of the works since the variable "Move" is always at 0)

```
int FDeclarations::PlaceMove(){
switch (Move)
{
case(1):
    if (turn == false) { TopLeft = 'x'; }
    else { TopLeft = 'o'; }
    break;
case(2):
    if (turn = false) { TopMid = 'x'; }
    else { TopMid = 'o'; }
    break;
case(3):
    if (turn = false) { TopRight = 'x'; }
    else { TopRight = 'o'; }
    break;
case(4):
    if (turn = false) { MidLeft = 'x'; }
    else { MidLeft = 'o'; }
    break;
case(5):
    if (turn = false) { MidMid = 'x'; }
    else { MidMid = 'o'; }
    break;
case(6):
    if (turn = false) { MidRight = 'x'; }
    else { MidRight = 'o'; }
    break;
case(7):
    if (turn = false) { BotLeft = 'x'; }
    else { BotLeft = 'o'; }
    break;
case(8):
    if (turn = false) { BotMid = 'x'; }
    else { BotMid = 'o'; }
    break;
case(9):
    if (turn = false) { BotRight = 'x'; }
    else { BotRight = 'o'; }
    break;
}


table();
    return 0;
}
```

Here are my variable declarations:

```
        class FDeclarations
{
    public:
        int PlaceMove();
        int GetMove();
        int CheckWin();
        void table();

    private:
        bool turn = false;
        int Move;
        char TopLeft = '1';
        char TopMid = '2';
        char TopRight = '3';
        char MidLeft = '4';
        char MidMid = '5';
        char MidRight = '6';
        char BotLeft = '7';
        char BotMid = '8';
        char BotRight ='9';
        bool XWin;
        bool OWin;
    };
```

Comment: You are redefining Move. Simply remove the `int Move` where you get the input

Comment: `'1'` is not the same as `1`. One is a `char`, the other a `int`.

Comment: Your `GetMove` function looks fine in and of itself, you're just confusing the `FDeclarations::Move` member with the `Move` _local variable_ inside `GetMove`, which is _shadowing_ the member. You should choose between returning the new move and modifying the member `Move`.

Comment: Also `if (turn = false)` - what is this? Equality comparison in C++ is expressed by `==` operator.

Comment: I don't see any point in your code where you'd call your `GetMove`. Where is the call? Show us how you call it.

Comment: Indeed, `if (turn = false) { ...` doesn't do what you think it does. You probably meant `if (turn == false){ ...`

Comment: @alter igel: If the OP intends to call that `GetMove` as `Move = GetMove()` (i.e. assign the returned value to the member), then there's nothing wrong with inner `Move`'s being a local variable.

Comment: If you adapt a the common coding style where variables are lower case, while methods and functions are uppercase, you'll avoid this kind of confusion in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your function

```
int FDeclarations::GetMove() {
    int Move;
    std::cin >> Move;
    return Move;
}
```

You declare a *new* variable called `Move` which is local to that function. This is different from the member variable `Move` declared in the class. C++ will prefer to bind to the function-level variable.

Unless you use the return value of `GetMove` to set the member variable `Move` in code you've not shown us, then the member variable `Move` will never change, causing your problem.

Comment: Well, maybe that is the intent! Maybe the OP plans to call that function as `Move = GetMove()`, where `Move` is the member. In that case the result will get into member `Move`.

Comment: @AnT Sure, like I said, "Unless you use the return value...". With the code given this is the best we can say.

Comment: This is why some programmers INSIST that you use `this->member`. This exact reason. You cannot accidentally do these kinds of things if you code like this.

Answer (score 2):

In `FDeclarations::GetMove()` you need to set the private member of your class `Move` to whatever the user will input instead of the local variable wich shadows the member one. So a quick fix will be:

```
int FDeclarations::GetMove(){
    std::cin >> Move;
    return Move;}
```

Comment: How do you know that? Maybe the OP plans to call that function as `Move = GetMove()`, where Move is the member. In that case the result will get into member `Move`.